# Show images on a monitor using raspberry pi via Wifi

Tags: pi-2, wifi, display

Consider a computer monitor hanging on a wall. Next to it is an raspberry pi with a wifi. Is it possible to create something like this? Using wifi it should be possible to send data (images) to raspberry pi. This will be output to a monitor, like an image gallery. Images can be any type (videos included).

Is it possible? Where does one start?

Thank you.

Comment: This is definitely possible. But your request is rather broad. Do you have any other limiting factors. Is your Pi supposed to host the WiFi or join an existing WiFi and therefore has access to the internet and use imgur, instagram. How do you want to put the image on? You can do it via a tweet, a plain TCP transfer, eMail, Bluetooth. And what is the desired environment? A browser, XWindow application, command line tool with raw access to the framebuffer or using OpenGL.

Comment: Your question basically breaks down to, "can a computer connection to another computer over wifi?". Of course it can. How that is accomplished is a **very** broad question. Try starting with [Google](https://www.google.com).

Comment: Valid point,  kwasmich. Before starting wanted to confirm that it is not only possible but also as Alves and Bex shared, I got an idea on  possible ways on how it is to be done. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, and in a myriad of ways.

One way would be to make a web page that displays a certain image with a javascript that reloads the page periodically.

Using `sftp` from any other machine, you could just upload another image with the same name in the same location. The next time the page reloads, the new image would be shown.

Answer (score 1):

There are DLNA technologies to stream media to devices on local network . A do it a lot with kodi media centre :

[How to install it on RPi](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_on_Raspberry_Pi)